# Find previous element of a table using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, html-table

I have a HTML table with following content.

```
<table class='main'>
<tr id='r1' class='tbl'>
    <td>V1</td>
</tr>
<tr id='r2' class='tbl'>
    <td>V2</td>
</tr>
<tr id='r3' class='tbl'>
    <td>V3</td>
</tr>
<tr id='r4' class='tbl'>
    <td>V4</td>
</tr>
<tr id='r5' class='tbl'>
    <td>V5</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

I can select a row by using jQuery code.
When I press "up" button in html, I want to swap the value of selected row's html with previous row.

Is it possible by using jQuery? I've tried several methods, but none of them is working.

Comment: Are you trying to move rows using arrow keys? I wasn't getting the "raw" part.

Comment: @Byron I updated the OP's question. Taking a stab in the dark that he meant row.

Comment: @Byron, KP; Sorry for the misspelled word... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recently had to do this for a project. Here's the code. Modify for your use.

```
                                        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">

                                            <thead>

                                                <tr id="table_buttons">
                                                    <td width="45px">&nbsp;</td>
                                                    <th width="40px" align="left">Item #</th>
                                                    <th align="left" style="padding:0">Item Name</th>
                                                    <th align="left" style="padding:0">Quantity</th>
                                                    <th align="left">Cost</th>
                                                    <th align="left">Extended Cost</th>
                                                    <th align="left" style="padding:0">Price</th>
                                                    <th align="left">Extended Price</th>
                                                    <th align="left" width="55px">Margin</th>
                                                </tr>
                                            </thead>

                                            <tbody>

                                            <tr id="copy_this_row" style="display:none;" number="0">
                                                <td>
                                                    <a href="#" class="row_up"><img src="<?php echo url::base(FALSE); ?>media/images/up_arrow.png" style="vertical-align:middle" /></a>
                                                    <a href="#" class="row_down"><img src="<?php echo url::base(FALSE); ?>media/images/down_arrow.png" style="vertical-align:middle" /></a><br /><br />
                                                    <a href="#" class="row_delete"><img src="<?php echo url::base(FALSE); ?>media/images/trash.png" style="vertical-align:middle" /></a>
                                                </td>
                                                <td field="item_number"></td>
                                                <td style="padding:0"><input type="text" class="text small" style="width:150px;" name="item[]" autocomplete="off" class="item_name" /><textarea name="description[]" style="width:200px !important; height:50px"></textarea><input type="hidden" name="item_id[]" /></td>
                                                <td style="padding:0"><input type="text" class="text small" style="width:50px;" name="qty[]" value="1" autocomplete="off" /></td>
                                                <td field="cost"></td>
                                                <td field="extended_cost"></td>
                                                <td style="padding:0"><input type="text" class="text small" style="width:50px;" name="price[]" autocomplete="off" /></td>
                                                <td field="extended_price"></td>
                                                <td field="margin"></td>
                                            </tr>


                                                <tr id="copy_before_this">
                                                    <td colspan="3">
                                                    <div class="tableactions">
                                                        <input type="button" class="submit tiny" value="Add Line Item" id="add_row" /> <!-- <input type="button" class="submit tiny" value="Add Product" />     <input type="button" class="submit tiny" value="Add Service" />-->
                                                    </div><!-- .tableactions ends --></td>
                                                    <td></td>
                                                    <td></td>
                                                    <td></td>
                                                    <td></td>
                                                    <td></td>
                                                    <td></td>
                                                </tr>
                                            </tbody></table>
```

jQuery:

```
                                $('.row_up').bind('click', function(){
                                        $(this).parent().parent().insertBefore($(this).parent().parent().prev());
                                        check_row_buttons();
                                        return false;
                                });


                                $('.row_down').bind('click', function(){
                                        $(this).parent().parent().insertAfter($(this).parent().parent().next());
                                        check_row_buttons();
                                        return false;
                                });


                                $('.row_delete').bind('click', function(){
                                        $(this).parent().parent().fadeOut(250, function(){ 
                                            $(this).remove();
                                            check_row_buttons();
                                            update_totals();
                                         });
                                        return false;
                                });


                                function new_row(item_name,item_id,description,quantity,price){
                                    var insert_this = $('#copy_this_row');
                                    var number = $('*[number]:last').attr('number');
                                    number++;
                                    var new_insert = insert_this.clone(true);
                                    new_insert.removeAttr('id');
                                    new_insert.fadeIn();
                                    new_insert.insertBefore('#copy_before_this').attr('number',number); 

                                    check_row_buttons();        
                                    auto_comp();    

                                    if(item_name){
                                        $('tr[number='+number+']>td>input[name=item\\[\\]]').val(item_name);
                                        item_info(item_id,number);
                                    }   
                                    if(description){
                                    $('tr[number='+number+']>td>textarea[name=description\\[\\]]').val(description);
                                    }   
                                    if(quantity){
                                        $('tr[number='+number+']>td>input[name=qty\\[\\]]').val(quantity);
                                    }   
                                    if(price){
                                        $('tr[number='+number+']>td>input[name=price\\[\\]]').val(price);
                                    }   
                                }


                                $('#add_row').bind('click', function(){
                                    new_row();
                                });


                                function check_row_buttons(){
                                    $('.row_up').show();
                                    $('.row_down').show();
                                    $('.row_delete').show();
                                    $('.row_up:eq(1)').hide();
                                    $('.row_down:last').hide();

                                    if($('.row_delete').size() == 2){
                                        $('.row_delete').hide();
                                    }
                                }


                                check_row_buttons();
```

This snippit also includes the ability to add rows, which can easily be removed.

Mainly pay attention to the $('.row_up') and $('.row_down') to see how to move the rows around using jquery and an image/object with class row_up and row_down -- This concept will help you write a custom solution for your project